# Count number of rows which contains same value

Tags: php, mysql

What is the MySQL query to count the total number of rows which contains the same value.
For example:

Consider a table `animal` which contains all animal names. If there are 5 rows in the table which contains the value `name` as `'cow'` then what would be the query for it?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT animal_name,
       COUNT(*) AS animal_count
FROM   animal_table
GROUP  BY animal_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CowCount 
FROM tableName
where animalName = 'cow';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) c FROM animal WHERE name='cow' GROUP BY name
```