# How to count the number of rows containing a specific number in it's column

Tags: php

I would like to echo a count how many rows are containing the same specific number.

I have a column called "**member_group_id**" in my db.

For example, the leader group id is "**4**" some members have this number assigned in the db, so I would like to do something like:

```
$countLeaders = count($row['member_group_id'] == 4);
```

How could I do that?

Here is my db query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM core_members WHERE member_group_id IN (4, 7, 8, 6, 11) ORDER BY 
    CASE member_group_id 
        WHEN '4' THEN 1  
        WHEN '7' THEN 2
        WHEN '8' THEN 3
        WHEN '6' THEN 4
        WHEN '11' THEN 5 
    END ASC, name ASC");
```

Here's my actual loop and desired result:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){        
    $group = $row['member_group_id'];
    $countLeaders = count($group == 4);
}

echo "<span>" . $countLeaders . " Leaders</span>";
```

Comment: please update your question with structure of your database and select query.

Comment: You want to write a piece of SQL to count or you want to process a PHP array for the count?

Comment: You would do the count in a query. `SELECT COUNT(member_group_id) AS member_group_id_count....`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of rows which contains same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799796/count-number-of-rows-which-contains-same-value)

Comment: I edited my post, I would like to know if it is possible to make it without the SQL query

Comment: Ok so now, do you want to count this as you process the resultset (in a while loop  for example?) Or do you `fetch all` of the resultset into one array?

Comment: @RiggsFolly my results are all fetched with mysqli_fetch_array($result) in a while loop

Comment: Please show us the relevant code. Check out the [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requriement. Without more speciic knowledge of what is really happening in your code we can only make guesses

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly, i edited the post, hope it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will just need to test the `$row['member_group_id']` for the value you are interested in, and then add to an accumulator if it is the right value

```
$countLeaders = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){        
    if ($row['member_group_id'] == '4') {
        $countLeaders++;
    }

    // other code if you have it
}

echo "<span>" . $countLeaders . " Leaders</span>";
```

Comment: This is working as expected, thanks a lot for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an array with multiple time same key at same level, i explain :

```
$test['hello'] = 1;
$test['hello'] = 5;
```

So key `hello` will contains only `5`.
If you want to count all keys with same value, you can write a code like this:

```
$array = array('1', '1', '2', 'test' => '1', '1', '2', '3', '1', '9');
$count = \count(array_keys($array, '1'));
// output of $count is 5
```

Search all keys corresponding to specified value, then count all keys.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you got all the result from your query as an array, with something like `pg_fetch_all` :

```
$result = [
    [
        'id'     => 'whatever',
        'and'    => 'whatever',
        'other'  => 'whatever'
        'fields' => 'whatever'
        'member_group_id' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'id'     => 'whatever',
        'and'    => 'whatever',
        'other'  => 'whatever'
        'fields' => 'whatever'
        'member_group_id' => 3,
    ],
    [
        'id'     => 'whatever',
        'and'    => 'whatever',
        'other'  => 'whatever'
        'fields' => 'whatever'
        'member_group_id' => 1,
    ],
]
```

And  you want to know how many of records have `['member_group_id'] == 1`

You can use

```
count(
    array_filter(
        function($item) { return ($item['member_group_id'] == 1); },
        $result
    )
)
```

`array_filter` walks through the array and keeps only items for which the function returns true.